# Which element from Soql query gets stored in key part of MAP while fetching records from SOQL query directly in map

Tags: apex, soql, map

If i have a query like

```
Map<Id,TER_Meter__c> mapIdToMeterPair=new Map<Id,TER_Meter__c>([Select Id,Name,(Select PAS_Customer_Consent_Flag_Effective_From__c,PAS_Customer_Consent_Flag_Effective_To__c,PAS_Consent__c from Consents__r),PAS_MSID_Effective_From__c,PAS_MSID_Effective_To__c,TER_Accepted__c from TER_Meter__c where Id in:meterIds]);
```

Currently key part of map is id type and contains id of record being fetched, in this case TER_Meter__c.

- Is there any way we can change what gets stored in the key part of the map while fetching value directly from query in to map.
- If so is it also possible to store value from inner query to key part of map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the key using `Map` constructor, it always uses the `Id` value. If you want to use any other key, you have to use a loop.

```
Map<Id, My_Object__c> records = new Map<Id, Object__c>();
for (My_Object__c record : [/*query*/])
{
    records.put(record.Some_Other_Field__c);
}
```

If you want to pull a key from your inner join, then you need to consider the possibility there are no child records.

```
for (...)
{
    if (!record.Children__r.isEmpty())
    {
        Child__c firstChild = record.Children__r[0];
        records.put(firstChild.Some_Field__c, record);
    }
    // else?
}
```